# Aligning UITextFields

Tags: xcode

Folks, new to xcode.  I am trying to align some UITextField fields on a view.  When I drag them to the view, they go all over the place.  However, I found a nice example on how to align them but it doesn't show how to accomplish this type of formatting/alignment.  The formatting/alignment I am trying to accomplish is the following (see attached image):

[image]

Please, if you need additional information ask me, do not downvote.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I figured out how to align the UITextFields.  Place all the UITextFields inside a Stack View, set the contraints and set distribution to "Equal Spacing"  Here are the details on how to accomplish this:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views